# Group action on affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring (finitely generated domain over the complex numbers, though I doubt I need this many hypotheses if any), $G$ is a (finite?) group acting on $A$, and $A^G$ is the ring of invariants. Is the map $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A^G)$ the same as the "quotient" map that just glues together prime ideals in the same $G$-orbit?

Comment: you just need the char$K$ does not divide the order of the finite group in auto($specA$).$spec(A_G)$ is the quotient variety. i.e $Spec(A)/G$.